# MySQL select from custom set and compare with table data

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm trying to solve which elements doesn't exists in my database. In order to do so I want to compare list of integers (output from external script) with data in table. How to do such thing like:

```
SELECT * FROM (1,1,2,3,5,8,13...) l WHERE l NOT IN (select id from table1);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably best done with a `left outer join`.  But, your problem is creating the table of constants:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select 1 as id union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 5 union all
      select 8 union all select 13 union all select 21 . . .
     ) ids
where ids.id NOT IN (select id from table1);
```

This can have odd behavior, if `table1.id` is ever `NULL`.  The following works more generally:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select 1 as id union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 5 union all
      select 8 union all select 13 union all select 21 . . .
     ) ids left outer join
     table1 t1
     on ids.id = t1.id
where t1.id is null;
```

EDIT:

The size of a MySQL query is dictated by the parameter `max_packet_size` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html)).  The most recent version has a limit of 1 Gbyte.  You should be able to fit 18,000 rows of:

```
     select <n> union all
```

into that limit, quite easily.  Gosh, I don't even think it would be 1 megabyte.  I would say, though, that passing a list of 18,000 ids through the application seems inefficient.  It would be nice if one database could just pull the data from the other database, without going through the application.

Comment: This list contains like 18k numbers... Hard to do such thing.

Comment: @J33nn . . . Then insert them into a table and use the table in the query.  Or, because most lists that long are generated by queries, just use that query as a subquery.

Comment: Query generated from external script and different database. Temporary table is the best approach I guess. But still it would be nice to do it some more sophisticated way.

Answer (score 0):

If your set to compare is huge I'd recommend you to create a temporary table `myids` with the only column `id`, put there all your 18K values and run query like that:

```
select id from myids where myids.id not in (select id from  table1);
```

Comment: Agreed but how to make it more universal and less brutal this is the question :)